# Copy a SSIS project/package from Visual studio 2017 to 2008 (partial ease accepted)

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2017

I have created several packages in Visual Studio 2017 (SSDT) SSIS solution, they are showing target server 2017. This was on my development PC. Now, upon completion of it, I am into a challenge. The Server on which, I am moving my packages, is having Visual Studio 2008.

I can understand that downgrading may not be right away possible, but I will still be happy if I can find a way to minimize my work (i can accept package by package or so). Please note I am accessing the other server on the Remote and not able to use Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V to copy and paste package objects, so if I don't get some easy ways then have to almost write the whole package again.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Visual Studio is not required on the server to run SSIS packages.  What version of SQL Server / integration services is installed?

Comment: I checked it and it is SQL server is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. I am not sure how to check integration services but it has Visual studio 2008 and I can BIDS as well. Do you see some hope here pls.

Comment: Any thoughts please on executing this 2017 package on sql server 2008 without altering the package? Can I deploy it?

Comment: SSIS changed significantly after 2008 R2 with the introduction of the project deployment model in sql 2012.  Bill's answer below about BIML is an option to downgrade the packages.  The other option would be to install a later version of SQL server on your server.  The would still be able to run 2008 packages so it should not impact existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [BimlExpress](https://varigence.com/bimlexpress) in your Visual Studio 2017 environment. Once installed, you should be able to right click on the package and with your new BimlExpress options, select `Convert SSIS Packages to Biml`

[image: Convert SSIS Packages to Biml]

In the Miscellaneous section of you SSIS project, you should have a BimlScript.biml file. That is the Biml representation of an SSIS package but in a much more terse, yet user friendly syntax. This XML describes in a version independent way what the SSIS package did. Here's where it's cool as a cucumber: The Biml for a 2005 SSIS package is exact same as a 2019 package and vice versa. The Biml Engine has to "know" how to translate the package definition into version specific .dtsx but the smart folks at Varigence have already solved that problem.

Now, you need to take that generic Biml and match it up to a Visual Studio 2008/2010 installation that has the Business Intelligence Design Studio (BIDS) bits installed on it. For SQL Server 2005/2008, BIDS *only* came on the SQL Server installation media as that is how the product is licensed. A developer license cost 25-50 USD but you can no longer purchase it. Hopefully, the target server has BIDS installed on it.

If so, *then* you need to find a copy of [BidsHelper](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=bidshelper) or maybe the renamed product [BI Developer Extensions](https://bideveloperextensions.github.io/) and then you can use the Biml engine embedded in that product to emit a 2008 correct package.

If none of that works, you can try getting a free 7/14 day license for [BimlStudio](https://varigence.com/bimlstudio) and the 2018 release still allows for the targeting of SSIS 2008.

Now, all of that supposes you haven't used any features in SSIS 2012+ that didn't exist in 2008 (Expression tasks, Parameters, project connection managers, etc) and I doubt a Script Task/Component is going to downgrade but the good news there is you should be able to mostly copy/paste the code into the 2008 version of the object.

Comment: @ billinkc -   Thanks a lot for detailed step by step. I could download the BimlExpress and get Biml of a simple package. I am not so clear on remaining part of your solution. What and how I use this Biml, please advise.

Comment: I could proceed further. Got the BIML file of a package. Copied at Remote server. Downloaded BIDS Helper extension and loaded the BIML file and then tried to convert BIML file to the package. It shows some errors, such that "Error 0 : The 'ConstraintMode' attribute is invalid - The value 'LinearOnCompletion' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd:Varigence.Languages.Biml.Task.ContainerConstraintMode' - The Enumeration constraint failed. Exception type: XmlSchemaValidationException
ValidateInput. There were errors during compilation. " Kindly advise.

Comment: I seem to be very close, tweaked the BIML part for most, changed to value 'LinearOnCompletion' to 'Parallel' not sure it is correct? but now perhaps due to connection managers, not able to still execute. Now latest error is "Error 0 : Node OLE DB Source: Could not execute Query on Connection xxxxxx.sa:..Login failed for user 'sa'."

Comment: Yes, LinearOnCompletion is newish. For 2008, the values are `Parallel` or `Linear`.  Your connection manager, based on the error message, is using a username and password and the scripting of the package likely didn't include it. Find your ConnectionManagers collection and then update/add the password into the connection string of the associated ConnectionManager

Comment: Your detailed response helped well. Certainly, it depends on package to package and what objects we used there. But it works.