# SSMS 18 & VS Community 2019 not recognizing that SSIS is installed

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

I have a new installation of SQL Server 2019, VS Community 2019 and SSMS 18.5 on Windows Server 2019.  I use a stored procedure in SQL to call a DTS package to pull data from an offsite database to our local SQL Server.  I have installed VS2019 with SSDT and then added the SSIS Projects extension. When I execute the stored procedure in SSMS I get the following errors.

> Description: The registry key "SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{692A88CF-7641-45B7-8E01-7BEE602D40EE}\DTSInfo" cannot be opened.
>   End Warning
>   Warning: 2020-05-06 10:49:38.42
>      Code: 0x8004801E
>      Source: Data Flow Task 1 Data Flow Task 1 (SSIS.Pipeline)
>      Description: Cannot find the "CurrentVersion" value for component {692A88CF-7641-45B7-8E01-7BEE602D40EE}. The CurrentVersion value for the component cannot be located. This error occurs if the component has not set its registry information to contain a
>   CurrentVersion value in the DTSInfo section. This message occurs during component development, or when the component is used in a package, if the component is not registered properly.
>   End Warning

I have uninstalled VS and SSIS Projects twice to try and correct any registration issues with no change in results.  In fact it's worse.  VS seems to be confused about the state of SSIS; see image.  I've check About Visual Studio and it shows SQL Server Data Tools v16.0.62003.05170 and SQL Server Integration Services v15.0.2000.94.  SSIS shows up as an installed program on the server.  I have rebuilt the package completely from scratch in VS 2019 and get the same errors.

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What version and edition of SQL Server do you have installed?  And do you have SSIS isntalled with the isntance?  SSDT only allows you to run SSIS packages in Visual Studio.  To run them from DTEXEC or any other host, you have to have SQL SErver Integrations Services installed.

Comment: What happens if you create a new SSIS project, does VS behave as expected?

Comment: Where did you get this project from? If you open the .dtproj file in text editor, which SQL Server / VS versions are mentioned in it?

Comment: Also, I wouldn't put too much trust into that green check mark. Go to the "Installed" node in the left pane and check if "SSIS Projects" is in the list. Also, check its version (the latest is 3.6 as of now).

Comment: I have SQL 2019.  I have figured out the issue in VS.  I repaired the install of VS and SSIS.  I had to reload the solution.  I am working on creating a new VS project.  When I call the package from SSMS I get the error messages that imply that it can't find SSIS.

Comment: The packages were originally created in VS 2008.  I've moved them from our old server to our new server with SQL 2019.  I had them successfully running using SQL Server 2017.

Comment: I have recreated one of the pacakges completely.  When it runs in VS 2019, it works the same as the original package.  When I call the new package from SSMS, I get the same errors -    Source: Data Flow Task Data Flow Task (SSIS.Pipeline)
   Description: The registry key "SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{692A88CF-7641-45B7-8E01-7BEE602D40EE}\DTSInfo" cannot be opened.

Comment: Rather than recreate, assuming there is a reason the package/project doesn't move well from 2008 to 2019, [Biml it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61611196/181965) from one to the other.

Comment: I can see the dtexec files installed in the BINN folders so I assume that SSIS is installed with the instance - all the installs have been complete on the same physical machine.  When I go to the SQL Installation Center with 2019 it takes me to the same download page to install VS 2019.  I have installed the SSIS Project extension in VS 2019.  Is there something else I need to do to associate it with SQL Server?  Thanks for the Biml tip!  If the issue turns out to be in the package it will help alot because I have a large number of similar packages.

Comment: My issue turned out to be one of the database property options.  The Compatibility Level was set to SQL 2008.  Once that option was changed to SQL 2019 the component pipeline errors went away.